# how to add the break to the data used as column heading in excel in php

Tags: php, excel, codeigniter

How to add the break to the data used as column heading in excel in php. I am having excel sheet from php that is in which I have to add heading for columns. I am able to do that but the problem is the data is more and I need it as one line after that how can we break it in excel sheet using php.

Can someone help me please thanks.

```
 $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A2', 'a.Please include the legends in the bottom of the table, like in the online version:<br>
 f – Based on "Actual Final Budget or Actual Spending"
 a – Based on "Actual Spending"
 p – Based on "Provisional Budget"
');
```

This is the heading, and at present am getting data up to f only.

Someone help me please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a "\n" character rather than an html break tag: PHPExcel uses MS Excel formatting, not HTML markup.

You probably also want to set the cell to wrap, and the row to autofit as well

Answer (score 0):

Add  semi-column after every statment

Comment: i have tried in another way it is working, i have a problem with mergin cells. i gave as follows it is showing error  $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B'.$i)->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);
  $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B'.$i)->getFont()->setSize(12);
  $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B'.$i)->getFont()->setBold(true);
  $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('B'.$i:'E'.$i); in the last line

Comment: Set margins like this:

$this->excel->getActiveSheet();
$margin = 1;

$pageMargins->setTop($margin);
$pageMargins->setBottom($margin);
$pageMargins->setLeft($margin);
$pageMargins->setRight($margin);

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = 'a.Please include the legends in the bottom of the table, like in the online version:'."\r\n";
$str .= 'f – Based on "Actual Final Budget or Actual Spending"'."\r\n";
$str .= 'a – Based on "Actual Spending"'."\r\n";
$str .= 'p – Based on "Provisional Budget"'."\r\n";
$this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A2', $str);
```

Try this one, it should be working.